# Action of the Gauge Group on the Configuration Space of Seiberg-Witten Theory

Tags: principal-bundles, spin-geometry, gauge-theory, 4-manifolds

In Seiberg-Witten theory, the group of gauge transformations is $Map(M,S^1)$.

For a configuration $(A,\psi)$, where $A$ is a unitary connection on the determinant line bundle, $\psi$ is a spinor, and $g:M\to S^1$ a change of gauge, we have

$(g, (A,\psi)) = (gAg^{-1} - g^{-1}dg, g\psi)$.

Where do we get this action from, and why is this the correct action to look at?

P.S. Remarks on notation: $g^{-1}$ is not the inverse map, but the map $x\mapsto g(x)^{-1}$. Also people usually write just $A - g^{-1}dg$ since $U(1)$ is abelian but I'm writing it with $gAg^{-1}$ to make clear I know what the expression means, I just wanna know how we derive it.

Comment: I am sure you know the transformation rules for Christoffel symbols. In that case, the gauge group is diffeomorphism. Here, it is similar. This can be found in any differential geometry books.

Comment: Usually the books I've been looking at on Seiberg-Witten theory only state the action, don't say how they came up with the action.

Comment: But that is the standard action of gauge groups acting on $\mathfrak{g}$-valued connection $1$-form of principal bundles. This is written in any standard textbooks of QFT/Yang-Mills Theory/Fiber Bundles/Differential Geometry. In Riemannian geometry, $A$ is replaced by Christoffel symbols, and $g$ is replaced by Jacobian. You should have already learnt this but you don't recognize it.

Comment: I have already learnt it, even before I posted this, and in fact I use it often. But mine is a why question: "Where do we get this action from, and why is this the correct action to look at?" This is why saying it is a standard action found in any book does not address the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for a physicists point of view, the argumentation is usually as follows:

So you want to formulate an action for sections $\psi$ in some vector bundle, say you write something like
$$
S[\psi]=\int\overline{\psi}~i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi
$$
in physicists notation (local coordinates). So formally, this is invariant if you replace $\psi\mapsto\text{e}^{i\alpha}\psi$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, or similarly, other "constant gauge transformations" depending on where $\psi$ should take values. Then physicists say (e.g. in an undergrad QFT lecture), that "for some relativistic reasons" any global gauge symmetry must be a local one, formally, that $\alpha$ should be allowed to be a function on spacetime. Then the above action is not invariant anymore, but replacing it by something like
$$
S[\psi,A]=\int\overline{\psi}~i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)\psi+\mathcal{L}_\text{free}(A_\mu)
$$
with another field $A_\mu$. This is invariant under $\psi\mapsto\text{e}^{i\alpha}\psi$ with $\alpha:M\to\mathbb{R}$ if you additionally claim that $A$ transforms as $A_\mu\mapsto A_\mu\pm \partial_\mu\alpha$ (i don't remember the sign). Hereby, $\partial_\mu+iA_\mu$ is called covariant derivative.

If $\psi$ is a section in some vector bundle, $g\psi$ is just the gauge transformed section, where simultaneously the connection form part of the configuration transforms as connection forms usually do, and your functional depending on $\psi$ and $A$ should be invariant under simultaneously transforming them both.

From a more mathematical point of view, you need to choose a connection form/a gauge in order to take derivatives in a vector bundle and the physics should not depend on this choice. Moreover, in a vector bundle two covariant derivatives are connected via a vector bundle automorphism/gauge transformation. These automorphisms can be identified with elements of your group $\text{Map}(M,G)$, acting as $\psi\mapsto g\psi$. On the other hand, this vector bundle automorphism can be associated with a principal bundle automorphism of the frame bundle (aka gauge transformation), and this gauge transformation acts on local connection forms as $A\mapsto gAg^{-1}-g^{-1}\text{d}g$. So on a configuration $(A,\psi)$, a gauge transformation acts by simultaneously transforming $\psi\mapsto g\psi$ and $A\mapsto gAg^{-1}-g^{-1}\text{d}g$ and invariance under this action guarantees that the physics does not depend on the choice of covariant derivative.

So you said "I just wanna know how we derive it", I don't know whether it can be derived in the sense that it necessarily must look like that, but I can give you the above physical motivation why an action like this is meaningful/worthy to be studied.

Comment: I really really enjoyed your answer! I did have something different in mind (so I created the response below), but if I could accept two answers I would do it.

Comment: Okay, I thought you ask for why one considers the combined action $(g, (A,\psi)) = (gAg^{-1} - g^{-1}dg, g\psi)$. If you ask for why the first factor (i.e. $A$) transforms this way: Well, that's just how local connection forms transform under chart transitions/gauge transformations (which is basically what you pointed out in you own answer...) and can be found in any book on that topic.

Comment: I decided to accept your answer since it was really useful! Regarding your comment, any book on the topic spells out the action of the gauge group, and separately spells out how local connection forms transform under chart transitions. But AFAIK they don't connect the dots (and neither did I at first). So my Q&A supplements the current literature as I know it. Now I can neatly answer "the action of the gauge group on **connections** comes from requiring the covariant derivative to commute with the action of the gauge group on **sections**," which I never found specified in any book.

Answer (score 1):

One way which I was able to understand this formula is the following:

Let the vector bundle with fibre a vector space $V$ be defined on an open cover $U_\alpha$ and transition maps $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha\beta}\to G\subset GL(V)$ (I'm avoiding using representation theory explicitly so let's assume matrix Lie groups). This means if $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\to V$ defines a section on $U_\alpha$ then $(p,\sigma_\alpha)\sim (p,g_{\alpha\beta}\sigma_\alpha)\in U_\beta\times V$.

A connection on this bundle is a Lie algebra valued 1-form. We can define it as collection of Lie algebra $1$-forms on the open cover, so maps $$A_\alpha: U_\alpha\to \Omega^1U_\alpha\otimes\underline{\mathfrak{g}}$$

and make them satisfy some compatibility condition so it's a well defined 1-form.

We can look at the corresponding covariant derivative for this, i.e. $$g_{\alpha\beta}\cdot(d+A_\alpha)\sigma_\alpha= (d+A_\beta)(g_{\alpha\beta}\cdot\sigma_\alpha)$$
should hold.

Expanding this we find $$g_{\alpha\beta}\cdot(d\sigma_\alpha+A_\alpha\otimes\sigma_\alpha) = dg_{\alpha\beta}\otimes\sigma_\alpha + g_{\alpha\beta}\otimes d\sigma_\alpha + A_\beta\otimes g_{\alpha\beta}\sigma_{\alpha}$$
$$g_{\alpha\beta}A_\alpha\otimes\sigma_\alpha = dg_{\alpha\beta}\otimes\sigma_\alpha + A_\beta\otimes g_{\alpha\beta}\sigma_{\alpha}$$
$$A_\alpha\otimes \sigma_\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}dg_{\alpha\beta}\otimes\sigma_\alpha + g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}A_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}\otimes\sigma_{\alpha}$$
$$A_\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}dg_{\alpha\beta} + g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}A_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}$$
where the $g_{\alpha\beta}$ can transition across the $\otimes$ since it is just a multiplication by a matrix, not involving derivatives like $A_\alpha$. The only care we took was to respect the order, for example $A_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}\neq g_{\alpha\beta}A_\beta$ since multiplication by matrices is a priori not commutative.

Using $g = g_{\beta\alpha}$ it becomes $$A_\alpha = gA_\beta g^{-1} - g^{-1}dg.$$

**Now,** the group of gauge transformations is exactly the set of maps $g :M\to G$ corresponding to "changes of basis."

Again, the covariant derivative should be independent of which basis we use. If we consider the same computation above, but seeing $A_\alpha, A_\beta$ not as the connection in different trivializing open sets but as the connection in different choices of gauge (i.e., $A_\alpha=g\cdot A_\beta$), then the we deduce what the action of the gauge group on connections should be, namely,
$$gA = gAg^{-1} - g^{-1}dg.$$